# SharedPreference: OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not working

Tags: android

Here's my use case.

The `PreferenceActivity` provides a selectable list of themes. When a user selects a particular theme from the list, I want the effect to take place immediately.

As of now, the change of theme affects all new activities that are launched but it  does not affect the currently visible `PreferenceActivity` and activities on back stack.

To overcome this, I decided to implement a `Sharedpreference` change listener which on change would clear all old activities from the `backstack` and restart the same class with the modified theme.

Here's what I tried.

```
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Settings.this,Settings.class);
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(newIntent);

                }

};
```

I tried simple log message like `Log.e("change", "pref changed");`
But it seems, this listener is simply not listening for changes.

Comment: Are you adding the listener with `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`?

Comment: No.. Do I have to use such a thing ?

Comment: You always have to add listeners to something. I added it as an answer, and also noted something that you should know before you run into issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register it with `SharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.


Also, keep in mind that the listener is kept in a `WeakHashMap`. This means that you cannot use an anonymous inner class as a listener, as it will become the target of garbage collection as soon as you leave the current scope. So make your listener an instance variable of your activity or make the activity itself implement the listener.